# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent after Move Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created a copy of my `Magento 2.2.4` in another domain to use as a development server. I have changed the `env.php` pointing to the new database, I have also modified the urls in the database but when entering the new domain it gives me this error.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/wwwdos9/public_html/vendetucasaenchina.com/app/bootstrap.php:1)
>   in
>   /home/wwwdos9/public_html/vendetucasaenchina.com/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php
>   on line 148

**Could you help me?**

Answer (score 0):

I think,

This issues is you are missing the some tag like start the

> You should check for any empty lines at the end of your .php files.Simply remove the empty line at the end of your script( after the final "?>" or "php>" string) and check your website again.

This tag you are missed your custom module or you last modified filed missed tag and check

> If your error points to functions.php, you can carry out the same procedure.

Second setp :-

> You import last database and file backup on your server

And after, showing same error showing??

Hope help this

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Mohit.  directly copy all the content of my domain in production with the exception of the images to the new domain that will be Development. Then I copied the Database. I modified the data of the new database in env.php and finally I modified the paths of the secure and insecure url in core_config_data, deleted cache. I even tried to put into production mode and it still gives me the same error.
It is simply a copy of the production version to a new production version. Any idea what is happening? because I haven't touched any php file.

Comment: Please check your env.php file you remove white space

Comment: I looked at the error logs and permissions and then tried enabling output_buffering in php.ini file. I guess that did the trick

Comment: enable the output_buffering = on and after check solve this error

Comment: solve error info me ??

Comment: Please check this links :- https://www.siteground.com/kb/cannot_modify_header_information__headers_already_sent_by/